Decryption Error Using RSA Private Key in Rust: 'decryption error'
I'm working on a Rust application that generates RSA keys and uses them for encryption and decryption. I have two functions: get_worker_keys which generates RSA keys and decrypt_user_id which attempts to decrypt an encrypted string using a private key. However, I'm encountering a decryption error in decrypt_user_id.
The snippet bellow is the js code that encrypted using the public key from the rust application then it sends it back to the rust application to decrypt:
    const key = new NodeRSA(selectedClients[0].public_key );
    const encryptedUserIdrsa = key.encrypt(userId, 'base64');

Code:
use rsa::{RsaPrivateKey, RsaPublicKey, pkcs1::LineEnding};
use rsa::pkcs1::{EncodeRsaPrivateKey, EncodeRsaPublicKey}; 
   
use rsa::Pkcs1v15Encrypt;
use rsa::pkcs1::DecodeRsaPrivateKey;
use base64;  


pub async fn get_worker_keys() -> anyhow::Result<(String, String)> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let private_key = RsaPrivateKey::new(&mut rng, 2048)?;
    let public_key = RsaPublicKey::from(&private_key);

    let private_key_pem = private_key.to_pkcs1_pem(LineEnding::LF)?;
    let public_key_pem = public_key.to_pkcs1_pem(LineEnding::LF)?;
    println!("|| private_key_pem {:?}", private_key_pem.clone());
    println!("|| public_key_pem {:?}" , public_key_pem.clone());

    Ok((private_key_pem.to_string(), public_key_pem.to_string()))
}

pub fn decrypt_user_id(encrypted_user_id: &str, private_key_pem: &str) -> Result<String, String> {
    println!("Starting decrypt_user_id function");
    println!("encrypted_user_id decrypt_user_id value {:?}", encrypted_user_id.clone());
    println!("private_key_pem decrypt_user_id function {:?}" , private_key_pem.clone());

    // Trim PEM data to ensure there are no extra spaces or newlines
    let pem_data = private_key_pem.trim();
    //println!("PEM data length: {} characters", pem_data.len());
    //println!("PEM data starts with correct header: {}", pem_data.starts_with("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"));
    //println!("PEM data ends with correct footer: {}", pem_data.ends_with("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"));

    if !pem_data.starts_with("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----") || !pem_data.ends_with("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----") {
        //println!("Invalid PEM format detected");
        return Err("Invalid PEM format".to_string());
    }

    // Attempt to create an RsaPrivateKey from PEM data
    //println!("Attempting to create RsaPrivateKey from PEM data");
    let private_key = match RsaPrivateKey::from_pkcs1_pem(pem_data) {
        Ok(key) => {
            println!("Successfully created RsaPrivateKey");
            key
        },
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Failed to decode private key: {}", e);
            return Err(format!("Failed to decode private key: {}", e));
        },
    };

    // Assuming encrypted_user_id is base64 encoded, decode it
    let encrypted_bytes = match base64::decode(encrypted_user_id) {
        Ok(bytes) => bytes,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Failed to decode base64: {}", e);
            return Err(format!("Failed to decode base64: {}", e));
        },
    };

    //println!("encrypted_user_id bytes: {:?}", encrypted_bytes);

    // Attempt to decrypt the bytes using the private key
    println!("Attempting to decrypt data");
    let decrypted_bytes = match private_key.decrypt(Pkcs1v15Encrypt, &encrypted_bytes) {
        Ok(bytes) => bytes,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Failed to decrypt: {}", e);
            return Err(format!("Failed to decrypt: {}", e));
        },
    };

    // Convert decrypted bytes to a string
    let decrypted_user_id = match String::from_utf8(decrypted_bytes) {
        Ok(s) => s,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Failed to convert decrypted bytes to string: {}", e);
            return Err(format!("Failed to convert decrypted bytes to string: {}", e));
        },
    };

    Ok(decrypted_user_id)
}

Issue:
When calling decrypt_user_id, I receive a "Failed to decrypt: decryption error" message.
Logs:
Here are the logs when running the code:
|| private_key_pem Zeroizing("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\ne9ZbBdtXa1m1bWiQociCVZPa4YwgmOrw0DLWRCsJMk9lGSSxlJ8wgi8=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n")
|| public_key_pem "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBCgKCAQEAwKXk9ymO0xutnFGNgtTac5wle/wpnOYwc6PXgmyXD7tS4Q8q+Xm0\npqf4Foxuu18Tyw01ulgUVgQ8tcSybTDTvPhjSC1vZ9VpYCflaMj3u6cnuaaXAm2B\nhLbGyKl/XDSIv2DmKpA9+/2SO5SWEjP+Aqb+T3tK8XF2K+vbbWsyBAiNmU4bgOUF\nkuMUewzOzDwt3/0ibviJT5KHsAkf7l4H89yrQEgaytHL089o42uMfv864gOANXBX\n0TDw9Yakh/GTgkzf4+cx7H0lprTqzem4zv2QnHjCn3yVNJ3R/p8MkDLnMHwlBfvA\nX9HkcSTv0fuiO9LQ5zo8eLlbDfpL2pwPFwIDAQAB\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n" 
Worker keys generated successfully
 
Starting decrypt_user_id function
encrypted_user_id decrypt_user_id value "nwU//Fr86Xb7DG/2QK2hCDmQPV6a6lutfLXuBVIWKrq8+uSgBSrcO+GVGf4TrQvAn1qMcBYWuptMQWRWcMCzVlyMGTYW4Ucq2V4q2YnILASbHPzChPR+l+b6ax8mGI0feK3Gtr3/zcxvIIXxSM33AlyhjPjwRrh/4o33apg2pd/dAq3bIxbLS39jKBRg/BrYfb8gcZGS5pn7vPmolSqzHrnbvJ45YLrFFYubdHhZ4PCYW/OIunHD1aWxj747RexNblHCYMGJyTNZ63BAJQkgZY9/VdZlaqkXnkvHBSti6DNssNp/5YxE4monLqDwXE1CRQws57xVfDFlqCmsV9Hitw=="
private_key_pem decrypt_user_id function "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\ne9ZbBdtXa1m1bWiQociCVZPa4YwgmOrw0DLWRCsJMk9lGSSxlJ8wgi8=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
Successfully created RsaPrivateKey

Attempting to decrypt data
Failed to decrypt: decryption error 


======================================================================================

i expected the decrypted uid but i get the error

`Attempting to decrypt data
Failed to decrypt: decryption error`


Check the documentation of the libraries you are using. node-rsa seems to apply OAEP as padding by default, while it looks like PKCS#1 v1.5 is used in the Rust code.
